# Families of function which are locally uniformly bounded but not uniformly bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following problem asked in conformal mapping and Riemann mapping theorem section of ponnusamy and silvermann complex variables with applications(page 394).

> question : What kind of families of function are locally uniformly bounded but not uniformly bounded.

Definition of both are clear to me but still not able to solve it.

Can you please tell how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example is $f_n(z) = nz^n$ on the unit disk. $(f_n)$ is not uniformly bounded since $\sup_{|z| < 1} |f_n(z)| = n$ is not bounded.

But for each $0 \le r < 1$ is  $\sup_{|z| < r} |f_n(z)| = nr^n$ a convergent and therefore bounded sequence, so that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded on all disks $B_r(0)$ with $r< 1$, and therefore a on all compact subsets of the unit disk.